# Primeng Calendar inside dialog problem depending on the body scroll

Tags: angular, primeng

I've tried many different approaches, as to set z-index, overflow to visibile and appendTo to the dialog itself, however, the dialog will cutoff if I am the bottom of the page using appendToBody

[image: Example of issue]

Here is the stackblitz to reproduce it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-3mxxnt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Note: you need to not have enough vertical height to reproduce it.

How do I solve this to never cut off?

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar problem. In my project (angular), the body of the page is being repositioned with the default scroll strategy.

To fix it, I found some css that I could apply at this page: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7390

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
position: initial;
width: initial;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This keeps the body at the same position, therefore allowing primeng calendar to render in the correct position.